# Unsequenced modification and access to "i"

Tags: c++

My ideas were quite simple.

I wished to copy, element by element, the data from an `std::vector<int>` `temp` to an `std::vector<int>` `data`.

```cpp
void copy(std::vector<int> &data, std::vector<int> &temp)
{    
    int i = 0;
    while (i < data.size())
        data[i]=temp[i++]; //unsequenced modification and access to "i"
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

The output is: `temp`={1,2,3,4}, but `data`={1,1,2,3}, even though `i`'s `std::cout` values are 1,2,3,4.

I wonder why.

Comment: You can do this with one of the insert overloads of the vector class. Don't reinvent. Your specific problem: don't increment and refer to i in one statement. That's undefined behaviour and the compiler might eat your cat. Also int is not the best choice for the type of i.

Comment: I've voted to reopen since there are more problems aside from the UB. But if folk still think it should be closed, please go ahead.

Comment: @Bathsheba What other issues?  The typo of missing a closing curly brace?

Comment: There's a const missing in the prototype, and int is not a good type for I.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The line

```
data[i]=temp[i++];//unsequenced modification and access to "i"
```

has unspeified behavior. The result of executing the line will be different depending on whether `data[i]` is evaluated first or `temp[i++]` is evaluated first. More dangerously, it will result in undefined behavior if `temp[i++]` is evaluated first for the last element of the vector.

Use

```
while (i<data.size()) {
    data[i]=temp[i];
    ++i;
}
```

As an alternative, use the `std::copy` function.

```
void copy(vector<int> &data, vector<int> &temp)
{
   std::copy(temp.begin(), temp.end(), data.begin());
}
```

Comment: And change the type, and the function prototype, then use the standard library function.

Comment: Undefined behaviour means anything can happen; your second sentence is more like a description of unspecified behaviour

Answer (score -1):

One might wonder why the behavior in a case like this isn't *defined* to be equivalent to incrementing in a separate statement following the one in question.  I imagine the reason is that processors have some ability to do post increment for you (see the lodsw family of instructions).  When using those instructions, the post increment must occur at the time you fetch the data.  So to guarantee the post increment followed all other uses of the incremented variable would require that that fetch be done last, or at least after all other uses of the rsi in that statement.  The designers probably decided that was too constraining.

Comment: Oh, I see where I went wrong here now - I meant for this to be a comment to R Sahu's answer, not an answer to the OP.  I'm interesting in improving my previous poorly received content - can I just delete this answer and repost it as a comment?  I know the system tracks deletions too - any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score -3):

Why people says about undefined behavior?

```
data[i]=temp[i++];
```

In this case, first, we will take value from temp[I] (example: y), then "i" will be incremented by 1 (i++), and after that, value from temp[i] (y in our case) will be stored in data[i], where "i" is already incremented by 1.

Comment: If that would be always the case and defined that way, then it would not be undefined behavior. Undefined behavior exists if the specs e.g. do not specify the order in which `data[i]` and `temp[i++]` have to be evaluated, so the index used could be the same for both vectors or could be off by one. And that could vary depending on the compiler, the settings or the code and is UB as of that. The specification might change that in future versions of c++, certain things that have been UB in c++11 are now well defined in c++17 and newer.

Comment: @t.niese undefined behaviour means anything can happen; the possibilities are not limited to the cases you list

Comment: - «if the specs e.g. do not specify the order in which data[i] and temp[i++] have to be evaluated, so the index used could be the same for both vectors or could be off by one.»
Hm, but this behavior is specified in specs as i know…
As we know, operator = have right to left associativity. So, expression on the right side (temp[i++]) should be calculated first.
«i++» means that first, value of I should be used in expression, and at the end, i will be increased by 1. This behavior also in specs.

Comment: So, we calculated temp[i], and var i was increased by one, it`s time, according right to left associativity, to set result of right expression to array: data[i].
This  behavior is specified in spec…

Comment: @GavriiL "associativity of an operator" is not related to "evaluation order of operands". Right to left associativity of = means that A=B=C is equivalent(I'm not sure this is a proper word) to A=(B=C), not (A=B)=C. That's all. It does not guarantee the right operand(value of temp[i++]) shall be evaluated earlier than the left operand(location of data[i]). http://c-faq.com/expr/evalorder1.html