# Please explain the output of the following C code

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h> 
int main()
{
char a[] = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' };
char* ppp = &a[0];
*ppp++;
printf("%c %c ", *++ppp, --*ppp);
return 0;
}
```

My expected output was **C B**. But Output is **C A**

Comment: You have undefined behaviour! Clang says this: **warning : unsequenced modification and access to 'ppp'** (for your `printf` line). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33743254/10871073).

Answer (score 0):

Use parenthesis in those cases so we understand what you want to do.
Do you increase the pointer ?

```
 ppp++;
```

Do you increase the value inside ?

```
(*ppp)++;
```